# How to solve this system of nonlinear ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I have a system of two nonlinear ODEs:

$${dk\over dt}= -\epsilon \tag{1}$$
and
$${d\epsilon\over dt} = -c{\epsilon^2\over k} \tag{2}$$

Where $c$ is a constant.

I tried to differentiate $(1)$ w.r.t to time and then substitute it in (2):

$$-{d^2 k\over dt^2} = -c {\left({dk\over dt}\right)^2\over k}$$
Or

$$k{d^2k\over dt^2} = c\left({dk\over dt}\right)^2 \tag{3}$$

But now, I have no idea how to proceed to solve this. Could you please point me how to solve this system of ODEs?

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

$$
\frac{k''}{k'}=c\frac{k'}{k}
$$

or

$$
\ln(k')'=c\ln(k)'
$$

or

$$
k' = C_0k^c
$$

Comment: Thank you. Now I can find easily the solution. Just a note: you made a typo in the second integral there is no prime.

Comment: Sorry, In my derivation, I made a typo in the sign. your ODE shouldn't contains the minus sign.

Comment: Thanks. Now it is fixed.